# Remove element from the DOM

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem within JavaScript when I attempt to delete a `li`, it will delete the entire `ul`. Does anyone know a solution for this?

```js
const add = document.querySelector(".add");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const cont = document.querySelector(".menu");
  const input = document.querySelector(".put");
  const newli = document.createElement("LI");
  const text = document.createTextNode(input.value);
  cont.append(newli);
  newli.appendChild(text);

})


const remove = document.querySelector(".remove");
remove.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const df = document.querySelector(".menu");
  df.remove(newli);

})
```

```html
<div class="parent-row">
  <h1>Add a new Post </h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="put">
    <button class="add">Add a Post</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove a Post</button>

  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Albenis</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

HTML:

```html
<div class="parent-row">
  <h1>Add a new Post</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="put" />
    <button class="add">Add a Post</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove a Post</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Albenis</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const add = document.querySelector(".add");
const remove = document.querySelector(".remove");

add.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const cont = document.querySelector(".menu");
  const input = document.querySelector(".put");
  const newli = document.createElement("LI");

  newli.innerText = input.value;
  cont.append(newli);
});

remove.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const df = document.querySelector(".menu");
  df.firstElementChild.remove();
});
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-almeida-z82lr?file=/index.html:262-561

---

### Your error

Your error was you were trying to get the `newli` constant from outside of its code block remember that `const` variables are scoped to there block.

---

### A different way of doing this

This way is a bit more simplified and allows you to delete anyone of the posts not just the last added.

```js
const postBtn = document.querySelector('#post')
const list = document.querySelector('#list')

postBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const text = document.querySelector('#post-text')
  list.innerHTML += `<li>${text.value} <button id="remove" onclick="remove(event)">remove</button></li>`
  text.value = ''
})

const remove = (e) => {
 e.target.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Make a post</h1>
  <input id="post-text" type="text" placeholder="Text"><button id="post">Post</button>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```